# Laravel 5 - htaccess HTTPS redirect on post routes doesn't work.

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have an application built with Laravel 5 acting as an API. I have the following in my .htaccess file to redirect all routes to https:

```
  RewriteEngine On

    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works fine for the following:

https://example.com/route

but throws a MethodNotAllowedHttpException if i try to access it with http. It correctly redirects to https, but seems to be not correctly following with the POST request, since all my routes only allow POST.

Is there any way to fix this without changing my routes to allow GET as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to force https, your RewriteRule is required to force an external redirect. In the case of your rule, you're forcing a 301 redirect (`R=301`). Most browsers and clients are designed to automatically follow redirects, but they (incorrectly) do so with a GET request.

So, when a client sends a POST request with data to `http://example.com/route`, your server responds with a 301 redirect to `https://example.com/route`, and then the client makes a GET request without the data to the new URL. As you can see, you can't just change your routes to accept GET requests as well, because the data sent in the original POST request will be dropped.

One option would be to add a rewrite condition to not redirect POST requests:

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, this pretty much defeats the purpose of what you're attempting to accomplish. This whole concept is to force https everywhere. It would be silly to enforce it everywhere except when POSTing data to your application.

Another possible option would be to change your 301 redirect to a 307 or 308 redirect. Even though clients aren't supposed to change the request method for 301/302 redirects, most clients do due to ambiguity in the specs and existing functionality. Because of this, 307 was added with the specific idea that if this status code is used, the request method MUST NOT be changed.

However, 307 is classified as a "temporary redirect", so it won't be cached and may affect your SEO. Additionally, this status was added in the HTTP/1.1 spec, so you may run into some clients that don't know how to process a 307.

By comparison, 308 is classified as a "permanent redirect", so it can be cached and not affect SEO. However, it was first introduced in June 2014, even later than 307, so client adoption may also be a concern there. That said, most modern clients shouldn't have an issue with either one.

Your best option is probably just to reject non-secure POST requests. Or, redirect them to an error page explaining you don't accept non-secure POST requests.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Forbid non-secure POSTs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ / [F,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: are  you saying that there is really no way to redirect http to https for post requests via the htaccess successfully?

Comment: @mykoman As mentioned in the answer, you can use 307 redirects instead of 301/302, but there are caveats that you may or may not care about.

Answer (score 0):

In apache.conf add following configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```