# HTTP not being redirected to HTTPS for certain Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, http-status-code-301

I recently switched to using HTTPS on my server, I found some code online that forces all incoming requests to the server to use HTTPS:

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And added `\App\Http\Auth\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class` to my middleware.

However now I have the following route:

```php
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

And the following controller:

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\FrontEnd\Controllers;

use App\Http\FrontEnd\Requests;
use App\Http\FrontEnd\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\FrontEnd\Requests\TestRequest;

use App\Commands\SendEmail, App\Commands\SendSMS;

use Auth, Input, DB, Session, Queue, Crypt;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function postCheck()
    {
        //
    }

    public function postConfirm()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Now that specific route won't work if I try to post to the following URL:

```
/test/confirm
```

It only works when I use https and I can't understand why or how to fix that.

Comment: Did you really mean `Route::controller('test', 'TestController');` or was it `Route::resources('test', 'TestController');`

Comment: Yes i meant route::controller

Comment: I don't think you can define a route like that.

Comment: What do you mean? That's what I've been using, check the laravel docs.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Didn't see that.

Comment: Are you sure it has to do with https because you don't seem to be handling your controller's namespace in your route.  Should be `Route::controller('test', 'FrontEnd\TestController');` I believe.

Comment: Actually that route is part of several other routes in a route::group.  I specify the namespace inside the route group so it affects all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to check out this question/answer: [Laravel 5 - htaccess HTTPS redirect on post routes doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399126/laravel-5-htaccess-https-redirect-on-post-routes-doesnt-work)

While that question deals with htaccess redirects, the principle is the same.

Basically, when a client accesses the `http` version of the URL, your code is responding with a 302 redirect to the client telling it to use the `https` URL. The client then makes a new request to the `https` URL, but it incorrectly uses a GET request and also drops the original POST data.

To resolve the issue of clients incorrectly changing the request method on redirects, they came up with a new redirect status code 307 that, when implemented, is specifically meant to redirect without modifying the request method. You can attempt to solve this issue by responding with a 307, but since it was introduced in HTTP/1.1, there is no guarantee the client will understand how to handle it.

To respond with a 307 redirect in your code:

```
return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri(), 307);
```

However, any workaround is actually just defeating the purpose of requiring HTTPS everywhere. If a client POSTs to a non-secure URL, the post data could already have been compromised. Your best bet is to actually just reject POST requests to non-secure URLs to make sure people don't think it is okay to POST to your non-secure URLs.

Comment: Wow this explains a lot! Learned something new! Thanks a lot for your time. :)