# Laravel 5.4: POST API routes give MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, api

It's so strange that the POST API routes doesn't work!
Check this simple POST route in `api.php`:

```
// This route doesn't work!
Route::post('/test', function (Request $request) {
        return 'test';
});
```

It gives me this error: `Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException`!

But if I change the request verb to GET, then both GET and POST work just fine!!! It's making me crazy!

```
// This route works on both, GET and POST!
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
        return 'test';
});
```

And yes, as you know the API routes simply don't use the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. So the middleware is not the issue obviously! And `php artisan cache:clear` is not also the answer :(

Did anybody had the same problem? Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Gonna sound crazy, but try removing the trailing slash from your request if it exists, so instead of `http://foo.dev/test/` try `http://foo.dev/test`

Comment: Yes, it's crazy.. I have also searched and some other people have this issue! But no one could come up with a solution so far... And there's also no trailing slash.

Comment: How are you hitting the API? Postman, ajax, other?

Comment: I'm hitting the API by postman.

Comment: Try to add in `/app/Http/Requests/Request.php` this method : `public function ajax()
    {
        return true;
    }` and test again !!

Comment: try swapping `http://` for `https://` or vice versa

Comment: @AlexHarris I am hitting my API on Postman by the POST method on a URL like this: `https://example.com/app/public/api/test`. So as you can see I am already using `https://`... Can you explain more in this? And what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting a redirect. If you POST to a url, and it returns a 301/302 redirect, the follow up request to the redirected url will be a GET request. This is why your POST route doesn't work, and why POSTing to your GET route does work. You will need to figure out what is causing the redirect. You can update your question with your `.htaccess` contents, as well as the url you're hitting or a postman screenshot.

Comment: Yes pay attention to the trailing slash ! I lost a day trying to figure out why Laravel 7 is sending error concerning Prefetch "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" this is misleading from the browsers including FF and Chrome and Laravel, I solved this by removing the / for the POST. Even more misleading is the fact that leaving the trailing slash with GET was OK but not with POST

Answer (score 4):

Oh yea! As @patricus also mentioned in comments, I was experimenting a stupid redirect without knowing it! Let me clear this for anyone else who is experienicng the same thing and don't know where this issue is coming from!

**You need to make sure the URL that you're connecting to is not going to be redirected behind the scenes whatsoever...**

e.g. in my own hosting panel, I have set to add WWW in all of my URLs... So when I was trying to access the `https://example.com/app/public/api/test` URL by POST method, I was getting the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error! Because my URL was redirecting to `https://www.example.com/app/public/api/test` and in redirection it will change to GET! And as I didn't set any GET routes... So obviously I was getting the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception :)

That's stupid, right? Yea, I know! Also make sure if your app is on a SSL domain, always connect to `https://` instead of `http://`. Because it is not only secure but also a redirection may happen again, without you knowing it! How? By your own `.htaccess` file that you have changed or your hosting support has changed it for you and you don't remember (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401543/247670) as well):

```
# Let's force using SSL on all of our URLs and also forbid non-secure POSTs

RewriteEngine On

# Forbid non-secure POSTs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ / [F,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or by services such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which help you be more secure and redirects all of your URLs from `http://` to `https://` if you have set this setting in your CloudFlare panel and again you don't remember that!

Comment: You saved my day Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mate. Your statement 'You need to make sure the URL that you're connecting to is not going to be redirected behind the scenes whatsoever...' saved my day! I have been wondering why my code works in my local dev server but not in my live server